# Same response for any call to a Mock Object

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Is it possible to capture any invocation on an object via a Mock and respond to it with controlled behavior?

For example, let's say I have a `class Foo` and I want to increment the number of times its calls are made via a Mock.

```
Class Foo(): 
   def __init__(self): 
       pass
   def func_one(self): 
       # do work
       pass
   def func_two(self): 
       # do work
       pass

Class EventListener(): 
   def __init__(foo): 
       self.worker = foo

   def consume(self, event): 
       if event == someVal: 
          self.worker.func_one()
       elif event == someOtherVal: 
          self.worker.func_two()
       else: 
          # do nothing
          pass

call_counter = 0

def test_EventListener():
   fooMock = mock.Mock("Foo Mock")
   # instead of mocking each function in fooMock that corresponds to a 
   # function in class Foo, is it possible to generically mock each function 
   # call and then respond with a uniform return or side_effect?
   # Start Example: 
   global call_counter
   fooMock.anyfunctionCall.returnValue = lambda : call_counter += 1
   # End Example
   eventListener = EventListener(fooMock)
 
   eventListener.consume(evt1)
   eventListener.consume(evt2)
   ...
   eventListner.consumer(evtN)
```

In my `EventListener` how can I increment a counter whenever a Foo "anyCall()" is made? A mock solution is acceptable but I don't know how to make Mocks do this yet.

Comment: You can intercept access to any attribute with [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

Comment: I've updated my question to show better what I am after. Still mulling around the correct question to ask. TY for response.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as creating a counter, and increasing the counter of the class whenever a function call is made.

```
Class Foo(): 
   counter = 0
   def __init__(self): 
       pass
   def func_one(self): 
       Foo.counter += 1
       pass
   def func_two(self): 
       Foo.counter += 1
       pass
```

Comment: perhaps the example is simple but I am after a generic solution to specifically capture the "INVOCATION" not necessarily any associated behavior. One nice thing I am after in asking this is the ability to uniformly respond to the invocation of any method calls within Foo.